# Why does this work, but not as I expected? Java conditional operator

Tags: java, conditional-operator

I'm learning Java and was doing this little time display. Then this part got tricky:

```
int second = 66;
second = ((second >= 0) && (second < 60) ? second : (second % 60) & (minute += second / 60));
```

Return second if between 0 and 60, else return second%60 and increase the minute. I expected it to work, but the output of second is:
`1`

Without the

`(minute += second / 60)`

and it worked. Change `60` to anything esle and watch the value of second changes as well. What's wrong with it?

Comment: Don't write code like that. It's unreadable to others, and incomprehensible to you. Why is there a bitwise `&` in there?

Comment: Wow, that is a complex line of code. Although it works, please refrain from writing such code. Code should be written in a readable and understandable fashion. It is not about minimizing the lines of code.

Comment: Your second line of code is overloaded. `(second % 60) & (minute += second / 60)` does NOT do `(second % 60)` "and then" `(minute += second / 60)`.

Comment: @ernest_k I expected it to work, but oh well. Finished it the time thing but I was wondering why this didn't work.

Comment: @ThiênNguyễn write it so that it takes less than 5 seconds for a person to understand what it does. That would be the best improvement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `&` is performing a bitwise `&` of the new `minute` value with `second % 60`, which seems very unlikely to be a good idea.

Given that you want a side-effect, I'd strongly recommend not using a conditional operator here - just use an `if` statement:

```java
if (second > 60)
{
    minute += second / 60;
    second = second % 60;
}
```

(If you need to handle negative values, you'll probably need more code - it depends on what result you want.)

The lesson to take away here is that the conditional operator is used to *compute a value*. In your case, you're really interested in taking *actions* rather than computing a value: "if the `second` variable isn't already normalized, make changes to both `second` and `minute`". That should make you think of an `if` statement rather than the conditional operator. There are plenty of times that you *can* use a conditional operator, but it would be clearer to use an `if` statement.

Comment: Thanks man. I already ditched the conditional operator and went with if instead, but still wonder why it didn't work, so I gotta ask somewhere. Thanks again for the help!